# java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime

Tags: database, jdbc, jmeter

I'm facing this error when trying to run a JDBC script on jmeter on a remote
machine                                                                              java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 54.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 54.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

Answer (score 4):

As per [Java Class File General Layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file#General_layout):

- `52` - Java SE 8
- `54` - Java SE 10

You either need to download the [Oracle JDBC Driver which supports Java 8](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/jdbc-downloads.html) and replace the one which you currently have in [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)

[image]

Alternatively you can upgrade your Java to Java 10+ (I think you can download [Java 11](https://openjdk.org/projects/jdk/11/) as Java 10 has been discontinued 4 years ago), higher versions of Java can normally load classes compiled with lower versions but not vice versa, in fact using the most recent stable Java version is recommended by the [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-memory-profiling#use) article.